# No module named dateutil.parser

Tags: python, django

I'm installing Rapidpro which uses django. I'm running `python manage.py runserver`

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 9, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/osboxes/dev/projects/rapidpro/rapidpro/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/osboxes/dev/projects/rapidpro/rapidpro/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/osboxes/dev/projects/rapidpro/rapidpro/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/osboxes/dev/projects/rapidpro/rapidpro/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/osboxes/dev/projects/rapidpro/rapidpro/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 123, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/osboxes/dev/projects/rapidpro/rapidpro/temba/utils/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from dateutil.parser import parse
ImportError: No module named dateutil.parser
```

I have followed the steps in this post: [ImportError: No module named dateutil.parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853474/importerror-no-module-named-dateutil-parser), but to no avail! (Both untaring and using pip)

I'm a complete python noob, so it's quite possible I'm overlooking something obvious. I'm installing on Ubuntu 15.04.

Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: are you using virtualenv ? if so, you most likely have a `requirements.txt` file. Open that file, and add `python-dateutil` module and run `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: First try installing them with apt.  If that doesn't work, follow the instructions by @EdySegura at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853474/importerror-no-module-named-dateutil-parser to get and install dateutil.  You may also need the six module which can be similarly installed. You may need a C compiler to build these modules which can be installed with apt.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to install python-dateutil.

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

If you are using a virtualenv make sure you activate the environment before running the pip install and also before you run the manage script as well.

Comment: This is like peeling an onion. Now I'm getting another error: `ImportError: No module named requests_oauthlib` I've done pip and apt... But this answer fixed my problem so I'll start another thread.  :-)

Comment: just go through your requirement and install them one by one, just matter of figure it out which component you required. If look for requirement.txt file if there is one you can install the req. at once pip install -r requirement.txt

Answer (score 0):

### Example:

> import dateutil.parser
>
> start_date = '2019-01-20 19:19:19'
>
> converted_date = dateutil.parser.parse(start_date).date()
>
> print("After converting date is : {}".format(after_convert_date))