# No module named dateutil.parser after dateutil

Tags: python, module, virtualenv

```
Python : 3.6.2
PIP : 9.0.1
virtualenv : 15.1.0
```

By Referring this [No module named dateutil.parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853474/importerror-no-module-named-dateutil-parser)

I installed **python-dateutil in virutalenv**

```
    (website) ❯ pip install python-dateutil  
    Collecting python-dateutil
      Using cached python_dateutil-2.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from python-dateutil)
    Installing collected packages: python-dateutil
    Successfully installed python-dateutil-2.6.1
```

But when i tried to import this in python shell

```
>>> from dateparser.date import DateDataParser
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dateparser'
>>>
```

what can be the issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `dateparser.date` you need to install [dateparser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dateparser). It's completely independent from `python-dateutil`.

```
pip install dateparser
```