# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dateutil.parser'; 'dateutil' is not a package

Tags: python-3.x

i am new to python and i have been using the following code

```
import dateutil.parser as parser
text = 'Thu, 16 Dec 2010 12:14:05 +0000'
date = parser.parse(text)
print(date.isoformat())
```

suggested by the example on the site .

but i am getting the 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dateutil.parser'; 'dateutil' is not a package'

i have already used the few solution from the similar question but non solved my problem

even after installing dateutil and also upgraded it with pip install python-dateutil --upgrade .

But still the problem continues .

Could any one help me out of this slump.

and also could some one help me understand dateutil and parser .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named dateutil.parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853474/importerror-no-module-named-dateutil-parser)

Comment: i am afraid its not . i tried the solution in those but non worked :( (just info working on windows 10 python 3 and with visual studiocode)

Comment: This is strange. I have a Python 3 running on Windows 10 and I´ve got the package. Maybe reinstall Python or install it from source (see the other post I´ve linked).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried your code and it works, try to `pip uninstall python-dateutil` and reinstall it again.

Answer (score 0):

This error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dateutil.parser'; 'dateutil' is not a package` may also occur if you have named the main program file you created as `dateutil.py` and try to run it as `python dateutil.py` or another file has the name `dateutil.py` in the same folder from which you run your program. Python will consider your program file as a module and try to find something in it that is naturally not in it. About where Python is looking for modules, see [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path).

In this case, rename your program file so that its name does not equal with the name of the imported module.