# Unable to convert a string to a datetime object in python and perform some time related calculations with it

Tags: python, python-datetime

What I am trying to do is to get the current datetime of a place using an API with python and extract datetime from it. The code that I have is:

```
import requests
import json
from datetime import datetime
import time

def get_current_time_from_api():
    response = (requests.get("http://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip")).json()
    return response["datetime"]

the_time = get_current_time_from_api()
```

When I print the response using `print(the_time)`, the response that gets returned is:

```
2020-05-06T10:04:51.368291+05:45
```

Then, I tried getting the converting the string to datetime using the function `datetime.strptime(the_time, "%X)` to get the time, I get the error `ValueError: time data '2020-05-06T10:09:52.009222+05:45' does not match format '%X'` So, what went wrong and how can I do things like this when the time is parsed from the string?

```
if(time == "10:00:00 pm"):
    #do something here
else:
    difference_in_minutes = "10:00:00" - current_time
    time.sleep(difference_in_minutes * 100) #sleeping for that many seconds
    #do stuff when the time is 10 pm
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be looking for the `fromisoformat` method.  Try this:

```
import datetime as dt
dt.datetime.fromisoformat(the_time).strftime('%X')

Output:
'21:37:54'
```

Comment: Yeah, I got the time but how do I do the comparison and operations with the time? @Rickey

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(
    '2020-05-06T10:04:51.368291+05:45', # your datetime string
    '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z' # format of datetime
)

# this is how you can add a day to date_object
new_date = datetime_obj + relativedelta(days=1)
```

This is wrong `time == "10:00:00 pm"`
you should use datetime_objects to compare, like:

```
if new_date > datetime_obj: # this is true.
    # You can do things here
    print("Yes")

# if(time == "10:00:00 pm"), should be done like this:
if datetime_obj.time().hour == 10 and datetime_obj.time().min == 10:
    pass
```

See for datetime formatting :
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

relativedelta:
https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html

Comment: It seems like there is no module named dateutil from the error that says:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dateutil'
`

Comment: Fix this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853474/importerror-no-module-named-dateutil-parser

Comment: How do I find the difference in minutes between 10 pm and current time? @thisshri

Comment: @MukeshAryal you can do this by `relativedelta(datetime1, datetime2).minutes`
Please see the documentation https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html